# Trajectory: Maths vs Physics

Tags: terminology, projectile

Why is the path followed by a projectile called [trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory)? Is it based on the same idea of trajectory (orthogonal & isogonal trajectories) that is taught in calculus (differential equation)? If yes, please explain how?

Comment: My internet search for the trajectory formula as stated in mathematics yielded the same formulas that I would expect to see in a physics class.  See https://byjus.com/trajectory-formula/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about physics.  It's more about historical naming conventions in English.  It might be appropriate for a different Stack Exchange network, but I'm not sure which one to recommend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Trajectory](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/trajectory) is simply an English word (with Latin origins) that means “path”. It has been co-opted as a label for various concepts in physics and mathematics, but none of these meanings is more fundamental than any other.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a time-dependent solution $\vec{r}(t)$, it is a process,a dynamics with known position, velocity and aceleration at a given time $t$.

If you exclude time from consideration, you will get a whole line in space, say, $y(x)$. No information about local velocity and acceleration is contained in such a line (whole path).